# CloudWatch agent CPU collected metrics not displayed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have installed CloudWatch agent on an EC2 micro instance running Ubuntu 16, mainly following this very good tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAnIhIwE5hY 
The tutorial shows the installation on a Windows instance but more than 90% of the explanations are working just fine on Linux too.

After I finished the installation, the CloudWatch collected metrics started to show just fine on my AWS CloudWatch console, except the CPU related metrics which are nowhere to be found.

Below is my json config file which I used. All the defined metrics are accessible except the CPU related ones `("cpu_usage_idle","cpu_usage_iowait","cpu_usage_user","cpu_usage_system")`

I created the json using the wizard.

Is there anything extra I should do in order to have those metrics available?

```
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
        "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "metrics": {
        "append_dimensions": {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
            "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
            "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
            "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
        },
        "metrics_collected": {
            "collectd": {
                "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60
            },
            "cpu": {
                "measurement": [
                    "cpu_usage_idle",
                    "cpu_usage_iowait",
                    "cpu_usage_user",
                    "cpu_usage_system"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "totalcpu": false
            },
            "disk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "used_percent",
                    "inodes_free"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "diskio": {
                "measurement": [
                    "io_time"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "mem": {
                "measurement": [
                    "mem_used_percent",
                    "mem_free"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
            },
            "statsd": {
                "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60,
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "service_address": ":8125"
            },
            "swap": {
                "measurement": [
                    "swap_used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add  `"resources": [
              "*"
            ],` after `cpu` and before `measurement`

Comment: Great! That was the solution! Thank you! If you add the comment as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer. I wonder why didn't the wizard put that `"resources": [ "*" ],` itself.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, i post the answer and share the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the `"resources": [ "*" ],` were missing.

From the docs :

> cpu – Optional. Specifies that CPU metrics are to be collected. This
>   section is valid only for Linux instances. **You must include at least
>   one of the resources and totalcpu fields for any CPU metrics to be
>   collected**. This section can include the following fields:
>
> resources – Optional. Specify this field with a value of * to cause
>   per-cpu metrics are to be collected. **The only allowed value is *.**

[CloudWatch Agent Configuration File: Metrics Section.](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html)